# Do these "references" exist as pointers in physical status or a virtual concept to explain?

Tags: python, c

I read the statements in "fluent python"

> The standard library offers a rich selection of sequence types implemented in C:
>
> Container sequences list, tuple, and collections.deque can hold items of different types.
>
> Flat sequences str, bytes, bytearray, memoryview, and array.array hold items of one type.
>
> Container sequences hold **references** to the objects they contain, which may be of any type, while flat sequences physically store the value of each item within its own memory space, and not as distinct objects. Thus, flat sequences are more compact, but they are limited to holding primitive values like characters, bytes, and numbers.

Container sequences hold **references** to the objects they contain,

Does the `references` exist as pointers in physical status or a mere imaginary concept to illustrate?

Comment: It's a concept: `x = list(); x.append(1); print(x)`; "x names (or 'references') the list". The implementation is a 'physical status'.

Comment: Does it occupy memory as a pointer? @user2864740

Comment: Any 'pointers' are implementation details - and yes, there is some indirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a CPython implementation detail, yes, they're all actually C level pointers to structs, where the structs contain the information about the object (including the reference counts, since CPython uses reference counting for memory management).

So when you do `a = [1]`, `a` itself holds a pointer to a `list` (`PyListObject` struct to be precise), which holds a pointer to an array of `PyObject*`s (in a field of `PyListObject`), and the first element stored in it is a pointer to a `PyLongObject` (the struct extending the base `PyObject` which corresponds to the `int` type at the Python layer on Python 3). Again this is all implementation details, but yes, you do have to spend a pointer's worth of memory to hold each such reference in CPython (unless you're using specially optimized C level containers like `array.array`, `numpy` arrays, `bytes`/`bytearray`/`str`, or `ctypes` arrays, which, by virtue of holding specific types, can store them as raw C arrays, without internal pointers to objects for each element).

The use of pointers under the hood is likely true in other Python interpreters as well, but there could easily be more layers of wrapping, abstraction, and indirection, to facilitate the needs of the different garbage collection strategies used by each.

Comment: so, hole reference is to hold the address of the object, a pointer bears an address of object it point to. It seem reasonable to treat reference as a pointer.

Comment: @riderdragon: Yes. The concept of "references" varies from language to language, so it can get confusing to use the term "reference" for what Python does when talking to someone from a C++ background (where references use pointers under the hood when necessary, but often get away with compiler level aliasing tricks that end up able to use the original object directly without actually storing a pointer to it anywhere). But yes, Python references behave much like pointers that are automatically dereferenced in all cases aside from assignment (where the pointer is copied, not what it points to).